# Number of unique values in an excel table column while a filter is active

Tags: excel

In an Excel table, one can filter the data of each column by clicking on the arrow next to the header. When clicking on this arrow, Excel displays a list of the unique values present in the column with a checkbox next to each values. This list changes when filters are applied on other columns. The number of unique values within a column if thus different depending on the filters that are applied.

I want to dynamically compute the number of unique values in each column and store that in a row above the table headers. These values should update when different filters are applied on the table, just like Excel updates the list when one clicks on the headers' arrow.

**Where I've got so far:**

- The option found [there](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/count-unique-values.html) `{=sum(1/countif(Tab[Column1] , Tab[Column1])}` (obtained by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) gives the number of unique values, but this would not take into account potential filters on the table.
- In the menu table tools > design, I can add a table row and use the `subtotal` function to obtain results that takes into account the filtering but this is mainly for simple operations such as `sum`. I can't figure how to count the number of unique values that way.
- Something like a structured reference `Tab[[#FilteredData],[Column1]]` could do the trick.

Comment: how many columns do you have? is it feasible to add a helper column (with subtotal) for each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that:

1) You are using table names in formulas

2) Your table is named "Tab"

3) The first column in your table is named "Column1"

4) An empty cell is equally to be considered a unique value

then place this **array formula**** in a cell somewhere within the same column as that containing "Column1", preferably such that it is external to the table itself:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(INDEX(Tab,1,COLUMNS($A:A)),ROW(Tab[Column1])-MIN(ROW(Tab[Column1])),)),MATCH(INDEX(Tab,,COLUMNS($A:A)),INDEX(Tab,,COLUMNS($A:A)),0)),ROW(Tab[Column1])-MIN(ROW(Tab[Column1]))+1),1))`

Copy to the right as required.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. The formula can be extended to the other columns by dragging with the mouse. Empty cells (blanks) are not counted as values (which is actually great for me, but seems to contradict your point 4).

Comment: It turns out the solution is slow (becoming unusable) for the size of tables I'm dealing with (10000 lines, 40 columns, some columns having always unique values). Can you find a way to improve the speed (espcially since I want to drag and drop this formula above most of the columns)?

Comment: I'm afraid not, apart from a few minor tweaks,which wouldn't amount to much in the long run. Over 400,000 cells, such constructions - which must not only consider filtered rows only, but also identify unique values within those filtered rows - are always going to push Excel to the limit.